# Is $Y$ open in $X\cup_f Y$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $A\subset X$ - a subspace and $f:A\rightarrow Y$ - a continuous map. Then we can define

$X\cup_f Y = X\sqcup Y/\{a\sim f(a)\quad a\in A\}$

Then the composition $Y\stackrel{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} X\sqcup Y\stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow}X\cup_f Y$ (where $\iota$ is the canonical embedding and $\pi$ - the quotient map) is a topological embedding, i.e. the image of $Y$ under $\pi\circ\iota$ is a homeomorphic copy of $Y$ in $X\cup_f Y$.

So says my book and I even seem to be able to prove this. However, suppose I want to glue a cylinder to a plane along the circle and consider the result in $\mathbb R^3$. I expect the topology of the resulting space to coincide with the one induced from $\mathbb R^3$. However, any point in the plane, lying on the circle along which I glued the surfaces together is an interior point of the plane, but not an interior point of the final surface. This means that the plane is not open in the final surface and so, the map $\pi\circ\iota$ is not a topological embedding.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it true that $\pi\circ\iota$ described above is a topological embedding?
2. Is it true that if the gluing happens in an ambient space and the spaces being glued together inherit their topology from it, the topology of $X\cup_f Y$ is also inherited from it?

Thank you.

Comment: Answer to your title: NO. Let $X=[0,1]$, $A=\{0,1\}$, and $Y=[2,3]$. Consider $f:A\to Y$ by $f(1)=f(1)=2$, then $Y$ is not open in $X\cup_{f} Y$.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't pick a better title that would fit the rules.    Can you help with the apparent contradiction which I outlined in the question?

Comment: Regarding your second question: Consider $I\times I$ as the ambient space, $X=(0,1]\times I$, $A=(0,1]\times\{0\}$, and $Y=[0,1]\times\{0\}$. Let $f$ be just the identity on $A=X\cap Y$. So as a set the adjuntion space is a subset of $I\times I$. But $(0,0)$ has different neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $I×I$ as the ambient space, 
$X=(0,1]×I,\ $ $A=(0,1]×\{0\},$ and $Y=[0,1]×\{0\}.$
Let $f$ be the identity on $A=X∩Y.$ Then the adjunction space $X\cup _f Y$  is the mapping cylinder $M_i$ of the embedding $i:(0,1]→[0,1]$, and it's not a subspace of $I×I$. For example a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $M_i$ is $\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid y<x<0.2 \}$, but this is not a neighborhood in $(0,1]×I\cup[0,1]×\{0\}.$ This also manifests itself in the fact that $(0,0)$ is in the closure of $(0,1)×(0,1)$, but there's no sequence in $(0,1)×(0,1)$ converging to $(0,0)$.

Your guess about $Y$ being embedded in $X\cup_f Y$ is right, but it's not necessarily an open (closed) embedding, only if $A$ is open (closed) in $X$.